# Leer archivo y almacenar en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo en el que cada línea contiene un nombre y una serie de números float separados por coma, el objetivo es colocar cada línea en una lista, y cada lista a su vez, en una nueva lista, creando así una especie de matriz. El archivo sería algo así:

```
Aquiles Baeza,5.1,2.0,4.8,7.0,6.1,4.7,6.1,5.4,3.8,3.7,6.6,6.1
Esteban Quito,6.1,6.6,6.3,7.0,6.0,6.8,6.7,5.5,5.4,6.3,6.5,6.8
Elsa Payo,3.0,2.1,3.9,4.5,3.6,4.2,3.7,4.8,1.3,1.5,2.4,3.3
Armando Casas,5.8,6.1,7.0,5.2,4.0,3.6,5.1,6.9,5.4,4.0,3.6,1.2
```

y la salida esperada seria una lista de listas:

```
['Aquiles Baeza', 5.1, 2.0, 4.8, 7.0, 6.1, 4.7, 6.1, 5.4, 3.8, 3.7, 6.6, 6.1]
['Esteban Quito', 6.1, 6.6, 6.3, 7.0, 6.0, 6.8, 6.7, 5.5, 5.4, 6.3, 6.5, 6.8]
['Elsa Payo', 3.0, 2.1, 3.9, 4.5, 3.6, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 1.3, 1.5, 2.4, 3.3]
['Armando Casas', 5.8, 6.1, 7.0, 5.2, 4.0, 3.6, 5.1, 6.9, 5.4, 4.0, 3.6, 1.2]
```

El problema está en que cuando trato de pasar los datos de la lista temp a la lista matriz, repite una y otra vez el primer dato (Aquiles Baeza), sin embargo, si imprimo el valor temp en ese punto, esta correcto, ¿cual es el error?.

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def leer_archivo():
    temp = []
    matriz = []
    with open('zzz.txt') as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            palabras = i[:-1].split(",")
            temp[:] = []
            for n in palabras:
                if (is_float(n)):
                    temp.append(float(n))
                else:
                    temp.append(n)
            print(temp)  
            matriz.append(temp)
    print(matriz)

leer_archivo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te repite siempre el primer elemento, sino siempre el último.

La razón es esta línea (bien extraña por cierto, me pregunto por qué lo has hecho así, o de dónde has sacado la idea):

```
            temp[:] = []
```

Esa línea altera **directamente** el contenido de la lista `temp`, vaciándola en vez de crear una nueva. Estás usando siempre **la misma lista** `temp` para guardar los datos de cada línea, por lo que cuando haces `matriz.append(temp)`, estás añadiendo siempre la misma referencia.

En cada iteración del bucle cambias los datos que había en esa lista por unos nuevos, pero la referencia es siempre la misma. Por eso al imprimir lo que contiene esa variable ves algo distinto cada vez, pero estás indirectamente cambiando lo que ya había en `matriz`, pues has cambiado los datos que había en la lista referenciada. Por eso al final `matriz` contiene cuatro veces los mismos datos (y corresponden a los de la última línea del fichero porque es la que queda tras la última iteración del bucle).

El problema se arregla si cambias esa inicialización por esta otra (mucho más habitual dicho sea de paso):

```
            temp = []
```

En este caso en vez de cambiar la lista que había en `temp` por una vacía, estás creando una lista vacía **nueva** (y reusando el nombre `temp` para apuntar a esta nueva lista, en vez de apuntar a la de la iteración anterior). De ese modo cada vez que añades `matriz.append(temp)` añades una referencia diferente, y así al final tienes los valores correctos.

Ya de paso se puede simplificar un poco el código. No es necesario quitar el retorno de carro final, pues la conversión a `float()` funcionará igualmente aunque haya ese retorno de carro. Por otro lado te puedes ahorrar la comprobación de si es o no es float, si inicializas la lista `temp` con el primer campo de la línea (el nombre) y procesas luego sólo los restantes campos. Finalmente la función `leer_archivo()` te imprime la lista, pero no la retorna. Lo correcto sería retornarla para que el programa principal pueda usarla para otras cosas. Por ejemplo, puede simplemente imprimirla.

Así pues:

```
def leer_archivo():
    matriz = []
    with open('zzz.txt') as f:
        for linea in f.readlines():
            palabras = linea.split(",")
            temp = [palabras[0]]
            for n in palabras[1:]:
                temp.append(float(n))
            matriz.append(temp)
    return matriz

datos = leer_archivo()
print(datos)
```

Y si usas algunos trucos, como el operador `*` para desempaquetado de tuplas y la función `map()` para aplicar una función a todos los elementos de un iterable, lo puedes dejar aún más corto:

```
def leer_archivo():
    matriz = []
    with open('zzz.txt') as fichero:
        for linea in fichero:
            nombre, *numeros = linea.split(",")
            matriz.append([nombre, *map(float, numeros)])
    return matriz
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy util tu respuesta